# using rewrite in Refl

Tags: idris

I am working through Chapter 8 Type Driven Development with Idris, and I have a question about how rewrite interacts with Refl.

This code is shown as an example of how rewrite works on an expression:

```
myReverse : Vect n elem -> Vect n elem
myReverse [] = []
myReverse {n = S k} (x :: xs)
    = let result = myReverse xs ++ [x] in
          rewrite plusCommutative 1 k in result
```

where `plusCommutative 1 k` will look for any instances of `1 + k` and replace it with `k + 1`.

My question is with this solution to rewriting `plusCommutative` as part of the exercies as `myPlusCommutes` with an answer being:

```
myPlusCommutes : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> n + m = m + n
myPlusCommutes Z m = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral m in Refl
myPlusCommutes (S k) m = rewrite myPlusCommutes k m in
                         rewrite plusSuccRightSucc m k in Refl
```

I am having trouble with this line:

```
myPlusCommutes Z m = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral m in Refl
```

because from what I can understand by using Refl on its own in that line as such:

```
myPlusCommutes Z m = Refl
```

I get this error:

```
When checking right hand side of myPlusCommutes with expected type
        0 + m = m + 0

Type mismatch between
        plus m 0 = plus m 0 (Type of Refl)
and
        m = plus m 0 (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                plus m 0
        and
                m
```

First off, one thing I did not realize is that it appears Refl works from the right side of the `=` and seeks reflection from that direction.

Next, it would seem that rewriting Refl results in a change from `plus m 0 = plus m 0` to `m = plus m 0`, rewriting from the left but stopping after the first replacement and not going to so far as to replace all instances of `plus m 0` with `m` as I would have expected.

Ultimately, that is my question, why rewriting behaves in such a way. Is rewriting on equality types different and in those cases rewrite only replaces on the left side of the `=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what is going on here we need to take into account the fact that `Refl` is polymorphic:

```
λΠ> :set showimplicits
λΠ> :t Refl
Refl : {A : Type} -> {x : A} -> (=) {A = A} {B = A} x x
```

That means Idris is trying to ascribe a type to the term `Refl` using  information from the context. E.g. `Refl` in `myPlusCommutes Z m = Refl` has type `plus m 0 = plus m 0`. Idris could have picked the LHS of `myPlusCommutes`' output type and tried to ascribe the type `m = m` to `Refl`. Also you can specify the `x` expression like so : `Refl {x = m}`.

Now, `rewrite` works with respect to your **current goal**, i.e. `rewrite Eq` replaces all the occurrences of the LHS of `Eq` with its RHS in your *goal*, not in some possible typing of `Refl`.

Let me give you a silly example of using a sequence of rewrites to illustrate what I mean:

```
foo : (n : Nat) -> n = (n + Z) + Z
foo n =
  rewrite sym $ plusAssociative n Z Z in   -- 1
  rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in        -- 2 
  Refl                                     -- 3
```

- We start with goal `n = (n + Z) + Z`, then
- line 1 turns the goal into `n = n + (Z + Z)` using the law of associativity, then
- line 2 turns the current goal `n = n + Z` (which is definitionally equal to `n = n + (Z + Z)`) into `n = n`
- line 3 provides a proof term for the current goal (if we wanted to be more explicit, we could have written `Refl {x = n}` in place of `Refl`).