# How to rewrite: Vect (S (S (n + m))) a -> Vect (S (plus n (S m))) a

Tags: idris

I am stuck with Idris (again, sigh). I am doing an exercise on merge sort from the type driven development with Idris book on chapter 10. I have this:

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.Vect.Views

sort2 : Ord a => (l: a) -> (r: a) -> (a, a)
sort2 l r = if l <= r then (l, r) else (r, l)

needHelp :  Vect (S (S (n + m))) a -> Vect (S (plus n (S m))) a
needHelp {n=(S n)} {m=(S m)} (x :: xs) = ?help

vectMerge : Ord a => Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n + m) a
vectMerge [] ys = ys
vectMerge {n} xs [] = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in xs
vectMerge {n=(S n)} {m=(S m)} (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
  let (f, s) = sort2 x y in
  needHelp (f :: s :: (vectMerge xs ys))
```

I have isolated the `needHelp` function so you can see the rewrite that I want to achieve. I tried this:

```
vectMerge : Ord a => Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n + m) a
vectMerge [] ys = ys
vectMerge {n} xs [] = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in xs
vectMerge {n=(S n)} {m=(S m)} (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
  let (f, s) = sort2 x y in
  let tail = (rewrite plusSuccRightSucc n m in s :: vectMerge xs ys) in
  f :: tail
```

But Idris complains:

```
When checking right hand side of Main.case block in vectMerge with expected type
        Vect (S (plus n (S m))) a

rewriting S (plus n m) to plus n (S m) did not change type letty
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rewrite` works with respect to your *current goal*, not wrt to the term you are trying to use to solve the goal (I tried to illustrate it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045544/2747511)).

So, here is a possible solution:

```
import Data.Vect

sort2 : Ord a => (l: a) -> (r: a) -> (a, a)
sort2 l r = if l <= r then (l, r) else (r, l)

vectMerge : Ord a => Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n + m) a
vectMerge [] ys = ys
vectMerge {n} xs [] = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in xs
vectMerge {n=(S n)} {m=(S m)} (x :: xs) (y :: ys) =
  let (f, s) = sort2 x y in
  rewrite sym $ plusSuccRightSucc n m in
  (f :: s :: (vectMerge xs ys))
```

`sym` in `sym $ plusSuccRightSucc n m` reverses the direction of `rewrite`.

Comment: Doh! I have to start thinking of proofs in terms of the right side being equal to the left side and not the other way around.

Comment: Well, this is sort of how dependent pattern matching works on the equality type. In `x = y : A` The first argument of type `A` is a parameter, but the second one is an index. And indices get rewritten in some branches of the pat-mat expression.

Comment: Getting wiser each day :) Thanks!